# Spring Boot deduced @Grab coordinates not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, groovy

Spring Boot CLI [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/cli-using-the-cli.html) for Groovy says:

> Spring Boot extends Groovy's standard @Grab support by allowing you to specify a dependency without a group or version, for example @Grab('freemarker'). This will consult Spring Boot's default dependency metadata to deduce the artifact's group and version.

However, my test application does work when group and version is omitted.
If I use `@Grab('freemarker')` instead of `@Grab('spring-boot-starter-freemarker')`, the application fails with a Whitelabel error. Is the documentation wrong? I am using the latest Spring Boot CLI 1.5.7.

```
.
├── app.groovy
├── static
│   └── index.html
└── templates
    └── hello.ftl
```

This is the project structure.

```
@Controller
@Grab('spring-boot-starter-freemarker')
class MyApp {

    @RequestMapping("/greet")
    String home(Model model, @RequestParam String name) {

        model.addAttribute("myname", name)
        return "hello"
    }
}
```

This is the main Groovy application file, `app.groovy`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home page</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>

        <form action="/greet">
            <label>Enter your name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name">

            <button type="submit">Submit</button>            
        </form>                        
    </body>
</html>
```

This is `index.html` home page, located in the `static` directory.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home page</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello ${myname}, today is a beautiful day!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Finally, this is the Freemarker template file,`hello.ftl`, located in the `templates` directory. The application is run with `spring run app.groovy`.

Comment: These issues persist with 2.0.0-RELEASE - @Grab("junit") likewise fails.